# Selenium: Unable to click on menu item

Tags: selenium, webdriver

I'm not able to click on the menu item (Create Defect...) as shown in the figure while testing my webapplication and getting below error

```
**org.openqa.selenium.ElementNotVisibleException: Cannot click on element**
```

[image: I would like to click on "Create Defect..."]

the below code clicks on the image (hand image) as shown in the figure

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@id='divToolbar']/div/table/tbody/tr/td[2]")).click();
```

and then the menu opens. Now I would like to click on the menu item.
I'm using below code for this

```
     driver.findElement(By.xpath("html/body/div[10]/div/div/div/div/div/ul/li[1]")).click();
```

but I got the above mentioned exception

This what I have in the html:

```
<div class="mmenu" style="display: block; left: 49px; top: 37px;">
<div class="mmenu-content">
<div class="mmenu-border" style="width: 231px;">
<div class="mmenu-inset" style="width: 231px;">
<div class="mmenu-group first-child last-child">
<div class="mmenu-column first-child last-child">
<h3>
<ul>
<li id="liemx360120335239.81635" class="link" menuuid="emx360120335239.81635">
<span class="icon">
<span>Create Defect...</span>
</li>
<li id="liemx172704021676.66638" class="link" menuuid="emx172704021676.66638">
</ul>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

Can you please suggest?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

have you tried **driver.findElement(By.xpath("//span[contains(text(),'Create Defect...']")).click();**

Comment: your answer helped me. now I am able to click on the "Create Defect..." with the below statement for IE driver.findElement(By.xpath("//span[text()='Create Defect...']")).click(); however, application opens a window for "Create defect" but not able to load. Just to let you know, for firefox my first trial works             driver.findElement(By.xpath("html/body/div[10]/div/div/div/div/div/ul/li[1]")).click();

Comment: i'm new to stackoverflow buti think i need 15 reputation to vote up your answer.

Comment: Okies, just did that. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem is that the second menu is invisible, and WebDriver throws `ElementNotVisibleException` if he operates on a locator which is not visible.
I think you have to keep the first menu open, as the second one to be visible when you try to click it.
I use [Actions](http://selenium.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/interactions/Actions.html) class.
Try to do following :

```
new Actions(getWebDriver()).moveToElement(driver.findElement(By.xpath(...))).perform();
```

and right after try to click the second locator. If you still have problem, try to chain both commands in the same action.